# Unable to resolve module Timers when calling setTimeout in componentWillReceiveProps function

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout

Am getting 500 error when calling setTimeout function inside componentWillReceiveProps function.

The below error Image i am getting when i am not debugging in chrome

[image]

The below error i am getting when i am debugging in chrome

[image]

You can see the below code for reference

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops){
        this.setState({isLoading:true})

        var data =[];
        if(nextprops.tasks.length == 0){
          //this.setState({isLoading:false,isEmpty:true})
        }else{
          this.setState({ dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(nextprops.tasks),isLoading: false, isError: false, isEmpty: false });
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          if(nextprops.tasks.length == 0){
            this.setState({isLoading:false,isEmpty:true})
          }else{
            this.setState({ dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(nextprops.tasks), isLoading: false, isError: false, isEmpty: false });
          }
        },5000);

      }
```

Comment: Check import section in the top of your file. There might be some 'timers' module imported automatically. It's was happening to me with one version of VSCode. It's because while typing vscode suggest you to use setTimeout from another module.

Comment: I have not imported any timers module seperately

Comment: Yes. it's auto importing when you work with autocomplete. Just check import section. If there's no import for 'timers' then I can't help with the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks bro ,It was auto-imported

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio automatically adds

```
import {setTimeout} from "timers";
```

Check your imports and remove it. setTimeout function doesn't need to be imported.